# How to create layout for store data in listview like any chat apk

Tags: android-layout, listview, chat

I am creating a simple layout for **store data in Listview**, **like any chat layout** with **9 patch image**.
A user can **add** or **remove** data in listview, (add data via EditText),
but I have no idea that how to set it.
Please can anyone give me solution?

Here is screenshot image:

[image]